# external css code appears in my html index page

Tags: css, html, apache

I have a HTML index file and a CSS file. The CSS file is stored under a separate CSS folder but when i view the code in my main page under view source the CSS code appears within the page. I have tried the same code on another machine and it works fine on that machine.

I m adding my css using this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
```

The output is appearing in the html file itself.

```
    <style>.bod{background-color:#ac83ff...............
    <script type="text/javascript">function registeruser(){va  
</head>
```

What could be the possible reasons or any solution  ??

Comment: Without showing us the code of what you have done, we can't really help you.

Comment: We can't guess whats going on... whats your code?

Comment: Do you use "Source code" (CTRL+U) or you see CSS in inspector tool? If in inspector - this might be ok.

Comment: This is the CSS code to include the CSS file: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

Comment: That doesn't help us much.

Comment: I think you should provide detail of your code so that, we can help you OR Please create a fiddle.

Comment: What browsers are you using on the 2 machines, what versions, what OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might have enabled pagespeed mod of apache check this https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-css-inline. you can desable it by

```
a2dismod pagespeed
```

Comment: anand your suggestion worked...... Thanks................